# How do the Android accelerometer and magnetic sensors contribute to orientation information?

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I know [how to get an orientation vector from the accelerometer and the magnetic field sensor](http://blog.mysticlakesoftware.com/2009/07/sensor-accelerometer-magnetics.html), but I don't understand why data from the magnetic field sensor is needed.  Could someone explain why?  On a related note, do I need to request updates with [SENSOR_DELAY_GAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_GAME) frequency for both when creating a game or can one (the magnetic field sensor, presumably) be updated less frequently without significantly affecting responsiveness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accelerometer data is purely used to detect which way is up and which way is down, whereas the magnetic field sensor is needed for the axis which determines north/south/east west. They are both required. Try using a regular compass while it's not flat, it won't work. The accelerometer essentially tells the orientation code how to translate the x/y/z results from the magnetic field sensors.

If however, you told your user that to use the app, they would have to lie their phone flat on its back, (or on its front, or side, etc) then you wouldn't need the accelerometer.

You don't need to use SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL might even be enough, it would certainly use less battery. However, if you need really accurate results, use SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST.

Comment: thanks a lot.  I'm curious why you don't think I'd need to use SENSOR_DELAY_GAME for a game.  (I'm concerned not just about battery but also about time in my listener.)

Comment: The names of the delays are arbitrary, I don't know why google chose the names or their values. But what I can say, is you always want to use the least intensive battery method that will work, your users will be grateful. There's no point draining battery when you don't need the extra accuracy. Just use the slowest one that has adequate performance for your specific needs

Comment: What about devices that only have one of the sensors, like the Kurio (which only has accelerometer). Are there any workarounds for them to still get usable tilt angles (for controlling a game etc)?

Comment: If you just want tilt angles for a game, the accelerometer alone should be fine. You only need magnetic field sensor for real-world orientation with respect to horizontal axes (north-south-east-west).